# Gmail filter to mark all incoming mail as read

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I would like to create a filter to mark all incoming mail as read in Gmail (I find the read/unread indicators distracting for my workflow)

Is there an easy way to do this?  I tried using a filter that searched for "is:unread" and marking it read, but Gmail gave me a warning saying that the "is" filter will never select incoming mail.

Comment: Can you consider selecting one of answers as accepted or write how answers are not suitable?

Answer (score 7):

Within the Gmail filter, for Size, choose "greater than 1 Bytes". For action, choose "Mark as read."

Comment: OP is not asking for size.

Comment: @serenesat That's not the point. All messages will be greater than 1 byte, causing them to match this filter and get marked as read. Alternatively you can also use the 'does not contain' field and enter random text that's unlikely to match any emails.

Comment: This is probably more reliable than my suggestion.

Comment: Also works with "larger than 0 Bytes". And even with "larger than 0 MB" (which is the default unit).

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
deliveredto:youraddress@gmail.com
action: Mark as read
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked, I just received a new email that wasn't marked read: http://cl.ly/image/1C1k330Z0X2Z

Comment: @emmby: How about some other action? I've set up a filter with that criteria but to move all messages to a particular label, and it seems to be working. Some people seem to have had some success with `to:*` or `from:*`. Try one of those.

Comment: It's interesting, the deliveredto: solution seems to work for some email and not for others.  I haven't figured out what the pattern is yet, it's inconsistent.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to have trouble getting a catch-all because most of the email you get is not actually addressed to you. It's mailing lists and such. And if you have multiple email addresses you're managing from one inbox...oy!